# which handsets support javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, mobile

does anyone know of a (relatively) recent matrix which describes which handsets support javascript in general and ajax in particular within their browsers, and what those browsers are?

I'm unable to find this info, via the obvious means.

The reason for this question is that I want to know how many Verizon handsets in particular would be included if I wrote a web app that detected onChange events in a form field and transmitted the form fields contents to the server at every character change (rather than when the user hits "Submit").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be your best bet:
http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html

But, it is not an exhaustive list.